# Add a border around every styled-component in react-native?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Often, during the creation stage of react native components, we add border-width to see exactly where the components lays out on screen.

```js
export const ScreenContainer = styled.View`
  border-width: 2px;
  flex: 1;
  padding-horizontal: 36px;
`;
```

Then, when finished we comment out the border. There can be 10's of components.

```js
export const ScreenContainer = styled.View`
  /* border-width: 2px; */
  flex: 1;
  padding-horizontal: 36px;
`;
```

Is there a global way to add a border (or other style) to every styled-component with the ability to easily turn it on/off?

This would significantly speed up our development time.

Comment: Nick's answer seems like a pretty good option, but if you just want a quick hack around it you could add this to the parent container for the styled components 
 > * {
    border-width: 2px;
  }

Comment: @Emma This seemed like a great option but I'm running into `Node of type rule not supported as an inline style`. Maybe this isn't possible in `react-native`?

Comment: hmm that's odd, I'm not too familiar with `react-native`, but maybe it has something to do with the nested selector. Have you tried including the rule with an `&` at the beginning?  `& > * { border-width: 2px; }` or `& * { border-width: 2px; }` ?

Comment: Yup... verified selectors aren't available in react-native.

Comment: @Emma RN doesn't have CSS. It has only styling properties and selectors aren't a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const DebuggableView = styled.View`
  border-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.debug ? '2px' : '0'};
`
```

Then wrap your app once with [`ThemeProvider`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#themeprovider) and instead of a bare `View` or `styled.View` use `DebuggableView`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Although this isn't a great solution I think it's the only one.  A slightly more generic approach (Views aren't the only thing with borders) is to simply use your `border-width` code, changing your last `0px` to whatever the real border is supposed to be, with any component it will affect. No need to create a completely new View type.

Comment: @GollyJer the idea in the view I suggested is that it comes with that border (or whatever you need to show in order to debug) built-in.

Comment: Any component which has its own border will override the debug one.

Comment: Yeah... I wanted a way to override all the borders even if they exist. Anyway... your answer was spot on. Now I just add `border-width: ${({ theme }) => (theme.debug ? '1px' : '3px')};` to all components with a border. The first number is the debug size and the second is the actual size. Then, when I set `debug: true` in the Theme, everything gets the 1px border. Thanks!